# Were the Na'vi ordered to kill Avatars?

Tags: plot-explanation, avatar

In *Avatar*, I don't understand why Neytiri was going to kill Jake.

Considering this,

- Avatars regularly went on day time field trips
- They carried weapons b/c the wildlife was the main threat
- There was no mention of an Avatar being killed by Na'vi
- Finally: When Norm asks Grace about the Na'vi when they first go into the woods of Pandora, Graces says,

> I am sure they are watching us now.

So, we are told that the Na'vi are most likely always watching them, which to me says that they are not in any danger from the Na'vi.

BUT, after Jake escapes the Banator attack, we see Neytiri about to shoot Jake with an arrow.
Considering this,

- It was still daylight (We are led to believe that night ops are not sanctioned and we do not know for what reason. It could be that the Na'vi are trained to kill at night? Speculation on my behalf)
- Jake had yet to upset the wildlife which Neytiri was angry at

[image]

So, what was the reason for Neytiri to kill Jake?
Were the Na'vi supposed to kill the Avatars on sight?
Or was this a spontaneous decision by Neytiri?

Answer (score 4):

Neytiri wanted to kill Jake because the previous Avatar expedition (with the famous female doctor) didn't go well and they all were excluded from the tree. The sponsors wanted the tree location because of the mines beneath it; something the Na'vi could never give up. There was a deep mistrust among them towards the avatars.

Comment: This seems more like speculation than anything in-universe. It's good speculation, but the fact that other Avatars hadn't been attacked since the school attack, there's no way confirm this is correct from the movie. Is there a Q&A or documentary where the authors/directors confirm this? If anything, I'd guess Neytiri would want to kill marines or Dr. Grace Augustine, not a new/random Avatar.

Comment: Well @KyloRen might have found a glitch in the story, think of it I had found another bigger glitch, Why did they want the mines that are beneath the tree when there are mountains of that material in another area; I guess "Pandora" just floating around. It seems much easier to get mine from there then to have all that fuss of years of struggling to get mines from beneath the tree.

Comment: You're forgetting that the easiest way to get Unobtainium, or any mineral, is through a large lode. Processing 2 tons of rock to get 1 oz of material isn't sustainable anywhere. If the deposit under the tree is reasonably pure without major processing, any amount of fighting becomes justifiable, even if it's inhumane and truly irrational in any other context. It's not a glitch in the movie, but rather human logic. Also, it's not a mine until there are miners mining.